# Error with javaScript (parseFloat) returns different result

Tags: javascript

**Hello, I'm trying to do a function that updates the values ​​of a subtraction, but when I try to do it, it returns me a difference of 0.1. I do not know what I'm failing, they could help me.**

```js
 function actualizarSaldoDocsConciliados() {
            var total = $("#total-7-importe").val();
            if (isNaN(parseFloat(total)))
                total = 0;
            var saldo = 0;
        $(".saldo-docconciliado").each(function (i, e) { saldo += Math.abs(e.value); });
            var moneda = $("#MonedaISO").val();
             @if (ViewBag.TipoDocumentoEnum == NimCRM.Model.Domain.TipoDocumentoEnum.VENTA_FACTURA)
                {
                    <text>
                         $("#saldoDocsConciliados").text("Total Saldo a Conciliar: " + Math.min(saldo, total) + " (" + moneda + ")");
                         $("#saldoDocsConciliadosCliente").text("Saldo  de la Factura: " + parseFloat((total - saldo)).toFixed(clienteDec) + " (" + moneda + ")");
                    </text>
             }
             else if (ViewBag.TipoDocumentoEnum == NimCRM.Model.Domain.TipoDocumentoEnum.VENTA_COMPROBANTEVENTA)
             {
                  <text>
                         $("#saldoDocsConciliadosCliente").text("Saldo del Comprovate de Venta: " + parseFloat((total - saldo)).toFixed(clienteDec) + " (" + moneda + ")");
                         $("#saldoDocsConciliados").text("Total Saldo a Conciliar: " + Math.min(saldo, total) + " (" + moneda + ")");

                    </text>
             }

        }
```

My problem comes here

[image]

[image]

It shows me a notorious difference of 0.01, but I already try in many ways but I do not see the error if they are so kind to help me I would appreciate it

Comment: Not all floating numbers can be represented in binary by a computer, just like `1/3` cannot be represented precisely as a decimal number.  You should not be using floating point numbers for any calculations that need to be precise (like money). https://www.floating-point-gui.de/